# SQL Server - Select query error

Tags: sql, sql-server

I got an error

> Column 'books.Name' is invalid in the select list because it is not
>   contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Code:

```
select Name, MIN(Date) as Date, Pub 
from books
where Date is not null
group by Pub
```

I would like to display Name of the old book and its publisher name.

Comment: use `group by Pub, name` in query

Comment: As SQL Server error messages go, this one is pretty clear.

Comment: @TabAlleman this has to be one of the most popular errors posted on StackOverflow

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help a lot here. I think @TabAlleman is onto something with his answer, but it's not completely clear.

Answer (score 6):

Every `non-aggregate` columns should be there in the `GROUP BY` clause.

Try this:

```
select Name, MIN(Date) as Date, Pub from books
where Date is not null
group by Name, Pub
```

Answer (score 2):

`Name` should be wrapped with an aggregate function, or you maybe want do like this:

```
select Name, MIN(Date) as Date, Pub from books
where Date is not null
group by Pub, Name
```

that means, you should group by Name too.

Hope it's helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Your deal with aggregations in your query. 
Columns can be part of aggregation calculation, like MIN(Column1), COUNT(*) or so. In other cases column has to be specified in a GROUP BY clause

So, Name column to be added to a group by clause:

```
select Name, MIN(Date) as Date, Pub from books
where Date is not null
group by Pub, Name
```

Answer (score 1):

> I would like to display Name of the old book and its publisher name.

Did you mean "oldest book"?

If that's the case, you don't do this with `MIN` and `GROUP BY`.

You do it with `TOP 1` and `ORDER BY`.

Comment: My table consists of columns: Id, Name, Price, Pub, Pages, Date, Pressrun. Like: 5, Corel Draw for professionals, 100, DiaSoft, 500, 2001-01-01 00:00:00:000. Now I want to show the Name of publishers and the oldest book from it, that is why I find min of date. But when I group all publishers, I cannot simply add name of those old books.

Comment: Create a new question, and word it this way:  "I want to show the Name of publishers and the oldest book from it."   Your original question was poorly worded and that's why it got closed.